# How to change the array source of a spinner (Android in eclipse)

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, android-spinner

I tried to ask this question before but I guess I didnt explain myself properly, so I will try again. I have a spinner (spinner5), I have created two string arrays (name_array and type_array) which are inside the values folder.

I also have two radio buttons (radiobtn1 and radiobtn2). I want to basically change the source of spinner5 when each radio button is selected.

> ```
> if (radiobtn1 is selected)
> then
>   I want spinner5 to display contents from name_array.
>
> else If (radiobtn2 is selected)
> then 
>   I want spinner5 to display contents from the type_array.
> ```

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Write below code in xml

    <RadioGroup 
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtpref"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton 
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Male" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radiobutton1"/>
        <RadioButton 
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Female"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radiobutton2"/>    
    </RadioGroup> 


    In Your Java file

    RadioButton radiobutton1,radiobutton2;
    String [] name_array,type_array;
    String [] temparray;

    temparray = (name_array or type_array) // use any which you want disaplay first and use temparray to pass your adapter 

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity_Name.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, temparray);
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_it‌​em);

    radiobutton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiobutton1);
    radiobutton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiobutton2);

    radiobutton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (isChecked) {
                    // you want spinner5 to display contents from name_array.   
                                     temparray = name_array;
                                     your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
        });

    radiobutton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (isChecked) {
                    // you want spinner5 to display contents from type_array.   
                                     temparray = type_array;
                                     your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });


    Thanks
```

Comment: I will create a adapter as normal and set its content to temparray?

Comment: and I only set the spinners adapter once?

Comment: I cant quite get this to work with an arrayadapter, is there a chance u can give me a code for an arrayadapter as well? Thanks

Comment: ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter(Activity_Name.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, temparray);  arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);         It use only once in your code

Comment: I put that into my code and my app just crashes when it loads

Comment: how does this link up the created arrays to the ones I made in the values folder?

Answer (score 1):

Its simple dude ... change the value of adapter in onCheckedChanged Listener and call notifyDataSourceChange.

If not clear ... you can also google for -- how to change value of spinner dynamically.

```
<RadioGroup 
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtpref"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Male" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton1"/>
    <RadioButton 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton2"/>    
</RadioGroup> 


In Your Java file

RadioButton radiobutton1,radiobutton2;
String [] name_array,type_array;
ArrayAdapter<String> ArrayAdapter;

RadioGroup radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
if(R.id.radioButton1==group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
    ArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getCurrentContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, name_array);
    NameSpinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter);
    ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}else{
    ArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getCurrentContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, name_array);
    NameSpinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter);
    ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Comment: I get an error saying that the method getCurrentContext() is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Set ArrayAdapter instead of setting it in xml... then keep updating the adapter..

Something like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html)

Comment: Still not sure how to apply that to my question. Can you help please